# How can I tell Reddit to ignore my Logo for the Thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, reddit

When a user shares content from my website, often the image appearing in the thumbnail is the logo of the website instead of the image itself.

How can I tell reddit to ignore the logo ?

I searched a lot and found answers on how to specify which image reddit should use with the `og image` meta tag, but I can't do that since my website is part UGC, meaning I wouldn't know what is the absolute URL for every image.

For example: [reddit not pulling scraping image on link post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478505/reddit-not-pulling-scraping-image-on-link-post)

**EDIT:**

This doesn't seem to be working on my end. Does it work on yours ?

```
<script>
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    return imgSrcs;
}var result = img_find();
$("meta[property='og:image']").attr("content", result[1]);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. If you don't know your image urls/what image to specify for reddit how would reddit know?

Comment: @kn I agree I may have been unclear. When a user uploads an image to my website, it's name is randomised to  a long string of alphanumericals. So the absolute url is something like: `website.com/page/fhj2kdshf4aje3dshfla8sdhfsjd`     with `fhj2kdshf4aje3dshfla8sdhfsjd`  being the image. My issue is that I don't know how to specify the `meta` tag `og:image` such that it points to the absolute url of the current image :/ `window.href` gives me `website.com/page/` , but how do I get the image name ?

Comment: @kn That's why I am wondering if there isn't a way to simply tell the scraper to ignore the logo since the uploaded image is the only other image on the website.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it made no real difference to helping you, wasn't able to find a way to do it I'm sorry

Comment: @MrSanchez Discussing it with you actually gave me an idea and I think it might work :D So don't be sorry, you actually helped :)

Comment: Well then I guess I'll undelete it XD, what ideia did ya get ? :P

Comment: @MrSanchez Updated question with the idea. I am not sure it works. But undeleting your question wouldn't be useful unless you have a working solution XD

Comment: That actually might work, good job ^-^

Comment: @MrSanchez Well, I was stuck until you posted your answer and I was like: "That won't work ! The only way this would work is if I could somehow scan the page to retrive the image url and... That's it !"

Comment: Ill see what I can do with the new script ;)

Comment: @MrSanchez Let's see if when sharing, you do get the correct thumbnail from your page ;)

Comment: Can you upload your html please?

Comment: Aint working on my end either, I'll try to see if I can fix it in any way.

Comment: @MrSanchez Ok :D

Comment: @MrSanchez Any ideas ?

Comment: @Coder1000 I got one but its very vague, if you can get a way to return the image to the page, you can then with javascript get it's absolute url, and return it to the meta tag

Comment: @MrSanchez Isn't this already what I am doing ?

Comment: I guess xD sorry I cant test code right now, windows screwed up my partition table so I gotta reinstall my arch xD

Comment: @MrSanchez Oh :O Good luck !

Answer (score 4):

Your code

```
$("meta[property='og:image']").attr("content", result[1]);
```

is almost the solution. Let's do the last step:

```
$("meta[property='og:image']")
    .attr("content", $('css_selector_of_the_img')[0].src);
```

So what is `css_selector_of_the_img`? Since you have the website logo, I'd assume that you had some HTML around your image. Probably the image has a className or placed into a container e.g. `css_selector_of_the_img` could be `div.content img` or `img.uploaded` whatever. And throw away your img_find function J.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

Adding `property="og:image"` to the `<img>` I want selected worked.

Comment: That shouldn't be correct per my understanding of the way reddit's system works.  I'll check and post an additional answer as to why this does work or why it shouldn't be used depending on what I find.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Wonderful ! Let's see what you find out !

Comment: OK, I looked over it, and I can't see _why_ this works.  [The scraping code](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L706-L774) only looks for `og:image` on `<meta>` tags (which, in fact, is the only place where it's valid according to the OGP docs as far as I can tell). So this _shouldn't_ be valid, and the fact that it is working is very odd.

One thing to note: it might be falling back to the "no image specified" code, in which case reddit will guess the image (algorithm [here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L706-L774)). [continued]

Comment: [continuing] It might be that you're getting lucky with the choosing the images you want now.

Setting the image via javascript won't work, since the scrapper only pulls HTML; it doesn't evaluate the javascript afterwards (you'd have to set the image serverside).

If you want to suggest against it choosing your site's logo, you could put "`sprite`" in the file name for the logo (which causes reddit to treat it as if the image were smaller, thus preferring user images).  I wouldn't recommend this, but it's an option.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Could you please give me your reference for the "sprite" thing ?

Comment: @Pokechu22 If you do so and I can see it works, I may be able to award you the bounty. But there are only 22 hours left, so be quick :D

Comment: [Line 766 of the scraping code](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L766)

Comment: @Pokechu22 Still waiting for you answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

the point of @Kosh Very's answer is to set the `og:image` tag with the first image in your page using jQuery, but this depends on the capability of reddit's scraper, which is whether the scraper can run javascript.

another solution is to use regex to parse for images in the UGC, and use it as your `og:image` url in your page generator.

hope that helps.

Comment: You do realise I have no idea how to do that ? :D

Comment: umm, did you build your own website? or you used the open source ones? I was assuming you build your own :D

Comment: I built my own. 4000 lines of code. But  "use regex to parse for images in the UGC" means nothing to me ^^ Could you please explain ? Where should I use regex ?

Comment: UGC means user generated content right? just checking if we're talking the same thing. if so, then you have 2 option, 1 is when the user save their content, or 2, when you display their content to the public. as for the how part, it depends on your programming language of preference, just search for it for your prefered language. for example: [find image url using regex for python](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=find+image+url+using+regex+for+python&oq=find+image+url+using+regex+for+python&aqs=chrome..69i57.10391j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)